# how to persist user login when browser closes in spring cloud architecture

Tags: angular, spring-cloud

I am currently working with spring cloud microservices architecture , I have oauth2 authorization server , zuul ,eureka discovery and resources servers . zuul proxy also has ui client angular . i am doing sso in zuul server and it works fine , i am able to get access tokens and relay to downstream services . My question is  when i login using sso after i close the browser login isnt persisted . i have also tried using remember me on oauth2 server which makes login persisted in oauth2 server but not in client (zuul and angular ui) . how do i persist the login in client?

Authorization server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource); 
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new 
    DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer 
endpoints) throws Exception {

    final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}


@Bean
protected JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("securekeys.jks"), "secure123".toCharArray());
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("securekeys"));
    return converter;
}

}
```

zuul (api gateway with angular)

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http
   .httpBasic().disable()
   .logout().and()
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/index.html","/*.js","/*.js.map", "/home", "/login" 
    ,"/").permitAll()
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
       .and()
   .csrf()

  .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

 }

 @Bean
 public OAuth2RestOperations 
 restOperations(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails 
 resource,OAuth2ClientContext context) {
   return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, context);
}  

}

@Configuration
public class JwtConfiguration {

@Autowired
JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;


@Bean
@Qualifier("tokenStore")
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
}

@Bean
protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter =  new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.cert");
    String publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
   }
}

 public class ViewController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }

}
```

zuul (application.yml)

```
spring:
application:
name: zuul-proxy

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
   register-with-eureka: true
   fetch-registry: true
   service-url:
   defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka      

security:
 oauth2:
  client:
    client-id: clientid
    client-secret: secret
    access-token-uri: http://localhost:8081/authserver/oauth/token
    user-authorization-uri: 
         http://localhost:8081/authserver/oauth/authorize

 resource:
   jwt:
     key-value:    
         -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----          MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIUDSFZSDAQEAqqgETvajhbRgnr/Gypwo/eJ95Df5l+0rOQzzHtt5KHCJRm86WmncAGMfGHcqYxFH3YBB14ZTU/bzMHun/qFxqxM720OFVAJQMdoO6UFXXOp9vHiQib/qCNeU8Y1QWTeqkUJ6AorPsHqH0VVbp1RdW0YBT4PRC2rZkfQlSIqs81INA3tFZt25Z10dU0Plb0vQIGs2gZ3AL2q8VTd7z4k5GY6CF7IJ53W6LbNNup0Vbln4H2CNn1wYLRKIEXhvRxhQpJepC6nNeCvr/8BeY/GxT6xRStIfwLIWkRZVJoJVhkDS9vkV6mSckXZu11OcQ0eiH34BxVB4/b0kvknUoioEgQIDAQAB
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----        

zuul:
prefix: /api
sensitive-headers:
  routes:
m1-service:
  path: /M1/**
  service-id: m1-service       
m2-service:
  path: /M2/**
  service-id: m2-service 
m3-service:
  path: /M3/**
  service-id: m3-service
```

Comment: Is the remember-me cookie being stored in the browser?

Comment: yes, the remember me cookie is stored in browser .

Comment: when i login again via zuul proxy it ask no credentials as the remember me is available on authserver but how to i detect already logged in user in angular client (zuul proxy) without sending any request to authserver . when i close browser zuul proxy (angular client ) forgets the user . how to remember the user in angular zuul proxy when i reopen the browser .

Comment: should i store access token in browser local storage if yes it it correct ?    and also if i store token in browser i have to handle refreshing the tokens in angular . presently i am able to refresh the token automatically using   OAuth2RestTemplate in the server side . currently access token or refresh token are not visible in angular client

Comment: There's no problem with doing it at server side. You could do the whole token refreshing cycle at server side. However you need to link each token with a session (it might be a java server session). As an example, to do it in zuul, it should take care of the current logged users in order to keep the link to their tokens internally. That's something the [keycloak adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.html) (OIDC) does. I have never used the Spring Security OAuth plugin myself, as you do, though.

Comment: Thank you @XtreamBiker , but my problem is still unresolved